# WASAPI Resampling / Windows Media Foundation

Tags: c++, audio, ms-media-foundation, wasapi

I'm writing a Pro Audio application using WASAPI.  This application runs a stream in exclusive mode, and resamples the audio data to and from a constant format in both directions (one resample between the capture device and the app, and another between the app and the output device).  There's a page on MSDN about an Audio Resampler DSP [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I'm not sure if this is the API I want to use.

The reason I'm not sure about it is the way the API is designed.  Using IMFTransform, I need a bunch of extra buffers that really only complicate the process, and the object is designed almost like a Direct3D object where I'm communicating with some driver (it has a command queue and the buffers have locks on them).

What I'm looking for is an API that resamples the data within my own app as fast as possible.  Is this the API Pro Audio applications are supposed to use for this purpose?  If not, what is the correct API?

Comment: I am using the Dmo-Resampler which is basically the same as the MF-Resampler for real-time resampling. It works fine. You should not have any problems with it.

Comment: @thefiloe Is the DMO-Resampler easier to use?  I'm not getting much through google, can you link me to something that would help?  I might use that instead.

Comment: You can find my c# implementation here: http://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/DSP/DmoResampler.cs

Comment: Audio Resampler DSP is correct API to use.